# Random password generator using

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate a random password with the following code I have. When I run it, I get undefined.

Where would my 'undefined' be coming from?**

````
```
````

// Assignment Code

````
   var charString = ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklnmopqrstuvwxyz", "0123456789", 
 "~!@#$%^&*()-_=+"];


 var userInput = [];

 var password = "";

 var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

    // Write password to the #password input
  function writePassword() {
 password = generatePassword();
   var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.value = password;

 }

 // Character length prompt
 function generatePassword() {
  var characterLength = 0
   while ((characterLength < 8 || characterLength > 128) || Number.isInteger(characterLength) === 
false) {
 characterLength = parseInt(prompt("How many characters would you like your password to be? (8- 
128)"));

   }

   var upper = false
   var lower = false
   var number = false
    var symbol = false

  while (!upper && !lower && !number && !symbol) {

  // Uppercase pop up
    upper = confirm("Click OK to confirm uppercase characters");

   // Lowercase pop up
   lower = confirm("Click OK to confirm lowercase characters");

   // Numeric pop up
   number = confirm("Click OK to confirm numeric characters");

   // Special charcter  pop up
  symbol = confirm("Click OK to confirm special characters (~!@#$%^&*()-_=+)");

  }

   if (upper) {
      userInput += charString[0];

   }

   if (lower) {
      userInput += charString[1]

   }


    if (number) {
     userInput += charString[2]

     }


    if (symbol) {
     userInput += charString[3]

     }

     var password = "";

   for (var i = 1; i <= userInput.length; i++) {
      var index = (Math.floor(Math.random) * userInput);
     password = password + userInput[index]
  }

  return password

}



// Add event listener to generate button
 generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);


```
````

Comment: Can you provide the error stack?

Comment: since your code is HTML/js, consider [creating a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to assist other reproduce the issue easily.  (you can hit `Ctrl+M` in the question editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code and made some observations in the snippet

```js
// Assignment Code

var charString = ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklnmopqrstuvwxyz", "0123456789", "~!@#$%^&*()-_=+"];

var userInput = [];

var password = "";

var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
    password = generatePassword();
    var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

    passwordText.value = password;
}

// Character length prompt
function generatePassword() {
    var characterLength = 0
    while ((characterLength < 8 || characterLength > 128) || Number.isInteger(characterLength) === false) {
        characterLength = parseInt(prompt("How many characters would you like your password to be? (8-128)"));
    }

    var upper = false
    var lower = false
    var number = false
    var symbol = false

    while (!upper && !lower && !number && !symbol) {

        // Uppercase pop up
        upper = confirm("Click OK to confirm uppercase characters");

        // Lowercase pop up
        lower = confirm("Click OK to confirm lowercase characters");

        // Numeric pop up
        number = confirm("Click OK to confirm numeric characters");

        // Special charcter  pop up
        symbol = confirm("Click OK to confirm special characters (~!@#$%^&*()-_=+)");
    }

    // userInput is an array, so you should push values into it.
    if (upper) {
        userInput.push(charString[0]);
    }

    if (lower) {
        userInput.push(charString[1])
    }

    if (number) {
        userInput.push(charString[2])
    }

    if (symbol) {
        userInput.push(charString[3])
    }

    var password = "";

    // join all array elements into a single one, and then split in order
    // to get an array of characters
    userInput = userInput.join("").split("");

    // You should start your for statement at position 0, not 1
    // and I guess it should be < than characterLength, not userInput.length
    for (var i = 0; i < characterLength; i++) {
        // Math.random is a function so you were missing the parenthesis Math.random()
        // also Math.random() should be times userInput.length
        // so they should be inside the same parenthesis
        var index = (Math.floor(Math.random() * userInput.length));
        password = password + userInput[index]
    }

    return password
}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

```html
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
<br>
<input type="text" id="password">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 var index = (Math.floor(Math.random) * userInput);
```

To

```
 var index = (Math.floor(Math.random() * userInput.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your types selection to avoid an infinite loop. Your problem was  your random index generation. There you go:

```js
var charString = ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklnmopqrstuvwxyz", "0123456789", 
 "~!@#$%^&*()-_=+"];

var userInput = "";

var password = "";

var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
  password = generatePassword();
  passwordText.value = ''; // Clear prev value
  passwordText.value = password;
}

// Character length prompt
function generatePassword() {
  var characterLength = 0
  while ((characterLength < 8 || characterLength > 128) || Number.isInteger(characterLength) === 
false) {
  characterLength = parseInt(prompt(`How many characters would you like your password to be? (8 
128)`));
  }

  var upper = false
  var lower = false
  var number = false
  var symbol = false

  while (true) {
    // Uppercase pop up
    upper = confirm("Click OK to confirm uppercase characters");

    // Lowercase pop up
    lower = confirm("Click OK to confirm lowercase characters");

    // Numeric pop up
    number = confirm("Click OK to confirm numeric characters");

    // Special charcter  pop up
    symbol = confirm("Click OK to confirm special characters (~!@#$%^&*()-_=+)");

    break;
  }

  console.log('Using upper', upper);
  console.log('Using lower', lower);
  console.log('Using number', number);
  console.log('Using symbol', symbol);

  upper && (userInput += charString[0])

  lower && (userInput += charString[1])

  number && (userInput += charString[2])

  symbol && (userInput += charString[3])

  var password = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < characterLength; i++) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * userInput.length);
    password += userInput[index]
  }

  return password

}



// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

```html
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
<input id="password"/>
```